# C# Class with multiple returns string and int

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how to describe this, but I'm going to do the best I can. I have a C# app that takes the API of my web app and uses it's JSON response as the data of the app. When a user clicks a button then it pulls the response from the url and parses it so it can be used:

```
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Nobody");
        var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri("http://localhost:45035/api/products/1"));
        var responsestring = response.ToString();
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(responsestring);

        Int32 Id = (int)o["Id"];
        string Name = (string)o["Name"];
        string Category = (string)o["Category"];
        float Price = (float)o["Price"];
        string Website = (string)o["Website"];

        label1.Text = Name;
        label2.Text = "$" + Price.ToString();
        label3.Text = "Category: " + Category;
        label4.Text = Id.ToString();
```

That works great. The problem is, when I have thousands of products, this app will have a thousand of code blocks just like this with only the DownloadString Uri changed. I wanted to turn this into one class so I can plug in the appropriate Uri (eg. http://example.com:45035/api/products/1 or http://example.com:45035/api/products/2, etc.) and from that get the Name, Category, Id, etc. from it so my code would be cleaner, but I can not figure out how to do that.

I tried something like:

```
        public static object responseinfo(string url)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Nobody");
        var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
        var responsestring = response.ToString();
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(responsestring);

        Int32 Id = (int)o["Id"];
        string Name = (string)o["Name"];
        string Category = (string)o["Category"];
        float Price = (float)o["Price"];
        string Website = (string)o["Website"];
    }
```

That allows me to call: jsonfind("http://localhost:45035/api/products/1") but I don't know how to get the strings out so I can use them in the text box like I did before.

I hope that this kind of makes since. It's my first question so if I need to change some, or a lot please tell me.

For the record I am using Json.NET do deal with the JSON responses.

Thanks,

Mitchell

Comment: Hi: frankly, I don't understand :(.  Q:  Your initial code block, ` var client = new WebClient();...`, lives in a C# class, doesn't it?  Q: If so, why don't you just make Name, Category, Price and Website members of that class?

Comment: That code is for a button: Button1_Click. When the button is clicked that first code block is executed.

Comment: OK - so why not make Name et al class members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most direct approach to your question is to use [`out` parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx):

```
public void GetTwoNumers(out int num1, out int num2) {
    num1 = 4;
    num2 = 2;
}
```

---

The better solution would be to pull the `WebClient` code out into a separate function that returns a `JObject`:

```
public static JObject WebRequest(string url) {
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Nobody");
    var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
    var responsestring = response.ToString();
    return JObject.Parse(responsestring);
}
```

Then, use that function in a number of other API call functions that each return their own class with the relevant fields:

```
public class Item {
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Category { get; private set; }
    public float Price { get; private set; }
    public string Website { get; private set; }

    private Item() {
    }

    public static Item GetFromUrl(string url) {
       var o = WebRequest(url);

        return new Item() {
            Id = (int)o["Id"],
            Name = (string)o["Name"],
            Category = (string)o["Category"],
            Price = (float)o["Price"],
            Website = (string)o["Website"],
        };
    }
}
```

And then calling this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string url = "...";
    var item = Item.GetFromUrl(url);

    MessageBox.Show("You found item #" + item.Id + " named " + item.Name);

    txtBoxName.Text = item.Name;
    txtBoxCat.Text = item.Category;
}
```

Note I used a static factory method `GetFromUrl` here, and made the constructor private. So you can only get an instance via that static method. Not entirely necessary, but a good technique here, IMO.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. Can you give a short example on how you would separate out the functions?

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions but I am having trouble understanding how I am supposed to use this. Maybe it's because I am frustrated :(. Say user clicks a button: Button1_Click. The button would tell the class where to navigate to, then I need it to return the Id, Name, etc so I can put that into a textbox (eg. textbox1.text = Name, textbox2.text = Category) Does this do that and I just don't see it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Added an example of calling the `Item.GetFromUrl` we just wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few options:

1) Create your own type and return it:

```
class JObjectReturned {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
}

public static JObjectReturned responseinfo(string url)
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Nobody");
    var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
    var responsestring = response.ToString();
    JObject o = JObject.Parse(responsestring);

    return new JObjectReturned() { 
        Id = (int)o["Id"],
        Name = (string)o["Name"],
        Category = (string)o["Category"],
        Price = (float)o["Price"],
        Website = (string)o["Website"]
    };
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < urls.Length; i++) { 
    JObjectReturned obj = responseInfo(urls[i]);
    // obj.Name, obj.Price, etc..
}
```

2) Return the JObject.

.. just don't return a Tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a class, lets sa Product, to store and retrieve the values?

```
puclic class Product
{
   int ID;
   string Name;
   string Category;
   string Website;
   float Price;
}
```

You could even use a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you realy wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public ProductDTO(string SourceURI)
    {
        this.SourceURI = SourceURI;
    }

    public void GetReady()
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Nobody");
        var response = client.DownloadString(new Uri(this.SourceURI));
        var responsestring = response.ToString();
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(responsestring);

        this.Id = (int)o["Id"];
        this.Name = (string)o["Name"];
        this.Category = (string)o["Category"];
        this.Price = (float)o["Price"];
        this.Website = (string)o["Website"];
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Category { get; private set; }
    public float Price { get; private set; }
    public string Website { get; private set; }
    public string SourceURI { get; private set; }
}
```

Regards